# Scala abstract class instance

Tags: scala, abstract-class

I am new to Scala. I have question about **List** class. This is an abstract and sealed class. It means cannot be instantiated, neither extended. So what is its usage? How can it be that something like following works?

```
val myList = List(1,2,3)
```

Would myList be a reference to the List object isntance?
Also, if **productElement** is an abstract method how can that be implemented?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding:

```
val myList = List(1,2,3)
```

When the compiler encounters an expression which creates a class instance without the `new` modifier, it looks up that classes companion object to look for a `.apply` method. In the case of list, it is defined as:

```
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

Thus, this compiles successfully. You can view this when asking the compiler to emit type information after the typer phase:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val l: List[Int] = scala.collection.immutable.List.apply[Int](1, 2, 3);
  ()
}
```

> Would myList be a reference to the List object isntance?

The run-time type of `myList` would be either a cons (`::`) or the empty list (`Nil`).

> if productElement is an abstract method how can that be implemented?

This is a compiler trick. `productElement` and `productArity` (and more) are both generated at compile time for any case class definition. For example, given the following case class:

```
case class Bar(i: Int)
```

The compiler generates:

```
// an incomplete view of the generated case class methods and fields
// omitted for brevity.
case class Bar extends AnyRef with Product with Serializable {
  <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> private[this] val i: Int = _;
  <stable> <caseaccessor> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def i: Int = Bar.this.i;
  def <init>(i: Int): yuval.tests.Foo.Bar = {
    Bar.super.<init>();
    ()
  };
  <synthetic> def copy(i: Int = i): yuval.tests.Foo.Bar = new Bar(i);
  <synthetic> def copy$default$1: Int = Bar.this.i;
  override <synthetic> def productPrefix: String = "Bar";

  // this is the relevant part to your question
  <synthetic> def productArity: Int = 1;
  <synthetic> def productElement(x$1: Int): Any = x$1 match {
    case 0 => Bar.this.i
    case _ => throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(x$1.toString())
  };
```

Comment: thanks. Hence `productElement` and `productArity` are implemeted by the compiler?

Comment: @toto' Yes, they are.

Answer (score 3):

`sealed` means it cannot be extended outside the file where it is defined. List is `sealed` but it does have 2 non-abstract sub-classes defined in the same file: `Nil` and `::` representing an empty list an a non-empty list respectively.

When you call `List(1,2,3)` you're not really instantiating the `List` class directly. It is syntax sugar for `List.apply(1, 2, 3)` which is calling the `apply` method on the `List` object (companion to the `List` class). And that method is (technically through some indirection) eventually producing an instance of either `Nil` or `::`.

You can see the list sub-classes here:
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L547
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L554

You don't need to implement `productElement` it is created by the scala compiler for all case classes.

Comment: thanks, clear. And what about how to implement its abstract methods like productElement ?